# Joining two files that both have duplicate rows

Tags: bash, join, duplicates

I am trying to join two files that have identical column 1 and different column 2:

File1

```
    aaa 1
    bbb 3
    bbb 3
    ccc 1
    ccc 1
    ccc 0
```

File2

```
    aaa 2
    bbb 2
    bbb 2
    ccc 1
    ccc 1
    ccc 0
```

When I try to join them with

```
    join File1 File2 > File3
```

I get

```
    aaa 1 2
    bbb 3 2
    bbb 3 2
    bbb 3 2
    bbb 3 2
    ccc 1 1
    ccc 1 1
    ccc 1 0
    ccc 1 1
    ccc 1 1
    ccc 1 0
    ccc 0 1
    ccc 0 1
    ccc 0 0
```

`join` is trying to expand the duplicates when all I want it to do is go line-by line so the output should be

```
    aaa 1 2
    bbb 3 2
    bbb 3 2
    ccc 1 1
    ccc 1 1
    ccc 0 0
```

How do I tell `join` to ignore duplicates and just combine the files line-by-line?

EDIT: This is being done in a loop with multiple files that all have the same column 1 but different column 2. I am joining the first two files into a temporary file and then looping through the other files joining with that temporary file.

Comment: in a comment (to a currently deleted answer by Cyrus) you mention doing this in a loop; you may want to expand on your situation by describing a bit about the loop requirement; it may be that a single `awk` (or `perl`, or ???) may be faster/more-efficient than running through a loop repeatedly processing the same files over and over again

Comment: How do decide whether a row is duplicate? Do these files always have even number of lines?

Comment: @markp-fuso I added an edit to explain the loop. Basically, joining two files into a temporary file then looping through the rest of the files joining with the temporary file (since join only lets you combine two files at a time).

Comment: This is a "merge line-by-line" problem (-> paste), since all files have identical first columns.

Comment: `paste File1 File2` is in the ballpark. Perhaps `paste File1 File2 | awk '{print $1,$2,$4}' to get more precise.

Comment: @AndreWildberg is there a clean way to paste the files together and not carry over column 1 every time (without manually printing lines with awk)?

Comment: Clean is relative, but you can try using cut like so `paste -d " " File1 <(cut -d " " -f 2 File2)`

Comment: on each pass through the loop the temp file obtains a new column?

Comment: are you 100% certain that all files have the same number of lines and the same set of values in the first column? if the answer is 'no' then please update the question with some sample data representing this issue and how the rows are to be joined (when there's a mismatch in the number of lines and/or values in the first column)

Comment: @markp-fuso in my case I am sure that row 1 is identical for every file. Column 1 is a possible outcome and column 2 is a count and the possible outcomes are the same for every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a suggestion from @Andre Wildberg, this worked best:

```
    paste File1 <(cut -d " " -f 2 File2)
```

This allowed be to loop through a list of files:

```
    cat File1 > tmp

    for file in $files
    do
        paste tmp <(cut -d " " -f 2 $file) > tmpf
        mv tmpf tmp
    done

    mv tmp FinalFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- all files have the same number of rows
- all files have the same values in the first column for the same numbered row
- the final result set can fit into memory

Sample input:

```
$ for f in f{1..4}
do
    echo "############ $f"
    cat $f
done

############ f1
aaa 1
bbb 3
bbb 3
ccc 1
ccc 1
ccc 0

############ f2
aaa 2
bbb 2
bbb 2
ccc 1
ccc 1
ccc 0

############ f3
aaa 12
bbb 12
bbb 12
ccc 11
ccc 11
ccc 10

############ f4
aaa 202
bbb 202
bbb 202
ccc 201
ccc 201
ccc 200
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { a[FNR]=$0; next }
        { a[FNR]=a[FNR] OFS $2 }
END     { for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) 
              print a[i]
        }
' f1 f2 f3 f4
```

This generates:

```
aaa 1 2 12 202
bbb 3 2 12 202
bbb 3 2 12 202
ccc 1 1 11 201
ccc 1 1 11 201
ccc 0 0 10 200
```